# How to give access to particular user for import/export actions in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, open-source, odoo-10

As I have so many user roles in my Odoo project. I want to remove import & export actions right from a particular user. Is there any way in which I can give them access and remove that actions. I didn't find anything on the web yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this module may help you but it is in v8 , so you need to migrate it.
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/remove_export_option/

Comment: I want for the Odoo V10.

Comment: So you can migrate it to v10

Comment: Can you please brief me out on how to migrate it ?

Comment: You have to change code as per new API guidelin, please refer to  odoo document

Answer (score 0):

After a long research, I found the solution for this problem on [Technoalerts](https://www.technoalerts.com) and it's very simple and easily accessible.

So for this problem, I used a module with a name called web_disable_export.

In this Module, only administrator can have the access to export any `field/model` details while no other user can do it.

Link for the module is here [Disable Export](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_disable_export/). It is available for all Odoo versions from V8 to V10.